python 'Unknown option: -e' message in Windows
I installed python on my Windows machine and added the python directory to the PATH variables.
The python keyword seems to be recognized in cmd.exe, but when I want to execute something, I only get the message:
C:\Users\user>python -version
Unknown option: -e
usage: python [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
Try 'python -h' for more information.

Also, when I try to install pyinstaller with pip install pyinstaller, I get the error message:
The command 'pip' is either misspelled or
could not be found.

Where is the mistake?

You need an extra dash. Try python --version

Once that works, try python -m pip install pyinstaller

it is kind of common to have single character parameters passable as a "word", So at the moment, python -version (with a single dash) looks like python -v -e -r -s -i -o -n to python

For the first error, try using --version.
-version is equivalent to -v -e -r -s -i -o -n.
Regarding the second error, it's difficult to know for sure but you could try running pip from python:
python -m pip install pyinstaller
